# executing python script for ssh connection not working

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I tried to execute a python script that will extablish an SSH connection but it won't work. It is successful when i do it manualy over the python shell, though.
I run a packet capture and i saw that my client machine is resetting the connection for some reason. is it a bug or it just wouldn't work with python2.7?
please help.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: can you give us what you tryied , and be more attentive before ask question , if you want we take the time to answer to you'r question , give us what you tryied

Comment: and before asking question , read rules

Answer (score 0):

We don't have much information since you didn't send any code, however did you check your firewall parameters ? Maybe your software is not allowed to run the connection